# turtle-graphics onclick() immediately calls function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

The code I have written should just wait until the user clicks on the turtle then it should go to (1000, 1000).

```
import turtle

ras = turtle.Turtle()
win = turtle.Screen()

win.bgcolor("black")
ras.color("blue")
ras.onclick(ras.goto(1000,1000))

win.mainloop()
```

But it doesn't, it just goes off immediately without any clicking on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this to work, you need to replace

```
ras.onclick(ras.goto(1000,1000))
```

with:

```
ras.onclick(lambda x, y: ras.goto(1000, 1000))
```

This *passes* a function to `onclick()` instead of the `None` that results from *calling* the function.  It also provides `x` and `y` arguments which are required for `onclick()` handlers, whether they're needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think that calling it as:

`ras.onclick(lambda: ras.goto(1000,1000))`

would work. The reason that it get's called is that, well,... you are calling it!

When you do `ras.goto(1000,1000)` outside of a function context, it calls the method

Comment: This won't work because the lambda function needs to accept the coordinates of the point that was clicked on the canvas (according to the documentation). The `lambda` you have doesn't have the two parameters it will be passed defined, so will likely cause some sort of error at runtime.